# How to define generic templated create function for subclass

Tags: c++, templates, subclass, mixins, crtp

I am working on cocos2dx game where for each subclass/scene I need to define something(macro) like this  CREATECOCOS2DSCENE(CustomSceneNameScreen);`  with following definition

```
 #define CREATECOCOS2DSCENE(T)\
 \
 static cocos2d::CCScene  * scene()\
 {cocos2d::CCScene * scene = new cocos2d::CCScene; scene->init(); T * layer =  new T;       layer->init();scene->addChild(layer); layer->release(); scene->autorelease(); return scene;}
```

*How can I avoid specifying macro on each screen?*

Comment: can you provide a use case or two?

Comment: @didierc If I need to create new screen,say LoginScreen(Which is actually derived from CCLayer), I will call `LoginScreen::scene()`, This method nicely wraps the layer in a root scene object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a macro for this, use an inline template function:

```
template <typename T>
inline static cocos2d::CCScene* scene()
{
    cocos2d::CCScene* scene = new cocos2d::CCScene; 
    scene->init(); 
    T * layer =  new T;       
    layer->init();
    scene->addChild(layer); 
    layer->release(); 
    scene->autorelease(); 
    return scene;
}
```

Comment: How to call this function; previously I was calling  *SomeSubclassofCCLayer::scene()* to create a new scene

Comment: @shakthi You need to specify the subclass as a template parameter: `cocods2d::CCScene* s = scene<SomeSubClass>();`.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a class template that is parameterized on the subclas `T` that you are eventually are going to use and that contains a public static function `create()` that does exactly what your macro currently defines

```
template<typename T>
struct Cocos2DSceneCreate
:
    // each subclass of Cocos2DSceneCreate is automatically a subclass of cocos2d::CCScene
    public cocos2d::CCScene
{
    // exact same content as your macro
    static cocos2d::CCScene* scene() 
    {
        cocos2d::CCScene * scene = new cocos2d::CCScene; 
        scene->init(); 
        T * layer =  new T;       
        layer->init();
        scene->addChild(layer); 
        layer->release(); 
        scene->autorelease(); 
        return scene;
    }
};
```

And then you use the **[Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)** (CRTP) to **mixin** the required behavior by deriving each subclass with the previously defined template with **itself** as parameter (this is where the word "recurring" comes from)

```
class SomeNewSubClass
:
    public Cocos2DSceneCreate<SomeNewSubClass>
{
    // other stuff
};
```

Note that `SomeNewSubClass` is in fact a subclass of `cocos2d::CCScene` because your `Cocos2DSceneCreate` is itself already a subclass.

Also note that this class template solution is a bit more complicated than the function template solution by @Yuushi. The added advantage is that it is easier to specialize the scene creation for specific types if you have a class template than if you have a function template. If you don't need to specialize, use his solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was on the fence about whether to add in the use of CTRP. At least this way the OP gets to see a few possibilities and can choose what s/he wants to use.